# How to delete a folder content except list of sub/sub folders and its contents?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to delete the content of Folder Main but keep Folder Main\Folder A\Folder AB and
Folder Main\Folder B\Folder BA with all its contents. But my actually code only keeps the Folder Main\Folder A and all its content..

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder Main
C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder Main\Folder A
C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder Main\Folder A\Folder AB
C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder Main\Folder A\File AB
C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder Main\Folder B
C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder Main\Folder B\Folder BA
C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder Main\Folder B\File BA
C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder Main\File 1
C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder Main\File 2 etc.


@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder Main"
SET "keepdir=Folder A"

FOR /d %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*") DO IF /i NOT "%%~nxa"=="%keepdir%" RD /S /Q "%%a"


GOTO :EOF
```

Can someone please help me?
I need to get it working at different pcs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest method is to use the [`robocopy` command](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) to list all the files and directories that need to be deleted while excluding the ones to keep, then delete them from the destination:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder Main"
set "_KEEP[1]=Folder A\Folder AB"
set "_KEEP[2]=Folder B\Folder BA"

rem // Build list of absolute directory paths to exclude:
set "LIST= " & pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%X in ('2^> nul set _KEEP') do (
        set "ITEM=%%~fY" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for /F "delims=" %%C in (^"!LIST! "!ITEM!"^") do endlocal & set "LIST=%%C"
    )
    popd
)

rem /* Build list of directories to delete with the list of exclusions applied;
rem    revert list in order to process it from bottom-level to top-level: */
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    for /F "tokens=*" %%D in ('
        robocopy "." "." "*.*" /L /E /IS /XX /FP /NFL /NS /NC /NP /NJH /NJS /XD %LIST:~2% ^
            ^| sort /R
    ') do (
        rem // Remove the upper-case `ECHO` commands to actually delete items:
        ECHO del /Q "%%D*.*"
        ECHO rd "%%D." 2> nul
    )
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

After having tested for the correct output, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` commands** in front of the `del` and `rd` commands!

---

If you also need to exclude certain files the approach needs to be adapted:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder Main"
set "_KDIR[1]=Folder A\Folder AB"
set "_KDIR[2]=Folder B\Folder BA"
SET "_KFIL[0]=%~nx0"
SET "_KFIL[1]=Folder C\abc.txt"

rem // Build list of absolute directory paths to exclude:
set "LDIR= " & pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%X in ('2^> nul set _KDIR') do (
        set "ITEM=%%~fY" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for /F "delims=" %%C in (^"!LDIR! "!ITEM!"^") do endlocal & set "LDIR=%%C"
    )
    popd
)

rem // Build list of absolute file paths to exclude:
set "LFIL= " & pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%X in ('2^> nul set _KFIL') do (
        set "ITEM=%%~fY" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for /F "delims=" %%C in (^"!LFIL! "!ITEM!"^") do endlocal & set "LFIL=%%C"
    )
    popd
)

rem /* Build list of items to delete with the list of exclusions applied;
rem    revert list in order to process it from bottom-level to top-level;
rem    the nested `for /F` loop is needed to remove leading spaces before sorting: */
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`
        ^(for /F "tokens=*" %%Z in ^('
            robocopy "." "." "*.*" /L /E /IS /XX /FP /NS /NC /NP /NJH /NJS /XD %LDIR:~2% /XF %LFIL:~2% ^
        '^) do @echo(%%Z^^^& rem/^) ^| sort /R
    `) do for %%J in ("%%~fI.") do (
        rem // Distinguish between files and directories:
        if "%%~fJ"=="%%~fI" (
            rem // Remove the upper-case `ECHO` command to actually delete files:
            ECHO del "%%I"
        ) else (
            rem // Remove the upper-case `ECHO` command to actually delete directories:
            ECHO rd "%%I." 2> nul
        )
    )
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Again after having tested for the correct output, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` commands** in front of the `del` and `rd` commands!

Comment: This works, but only for folders. I can't exclude a file in EX Folder CC called abc.txt. Do you know the way to include files in sub oder sub/sub folders as well?

Comment: It's also a serious abuse of robocopy and overly complex.

Comment: @jwdonahue: So you think its possible to get this working excluding folders (or files) in folders on an other way?

Comment: @jwdonahue, of course you could loop over the directory tree with `for` loops and do all the exclusion stuff manually to avoid misusing `robocopy`, but wouldn't this be even more complex then? Anyway, the main target of my approach is to not touch the items to exclude (like copying/moving them away, removing the whole directory tree, then restoring the exclusion items), because you may lose information (creation date/time, ownership, non-inherited access rights, etc.), and copying (or moving to another drive) is a waste of time, so I come to `robocopy` and its `/XD` option...

Comment: @Alkenix, yes, this is possible; wait a minute, then I'll update the answer accordingly...

Comment: @Alenix, yes, see Gerhard Barnard's answer.  It's simple, easy to grok, uses less memory and probably runs faster as well.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a list of items to exclude:

```
@echo off
set "sourcedir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder Main"
SET exclude="Folder A\Folder AB" "Folder B\Folder BA"
for %%i in (%exclude%) do for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%"') do if /i not "%sourcedir%\%%~i" == "%sourcedir%\%%~nxa\%%~ni" echo rd /S /Q "%%a"
```

You can delete `echo` before `rd` once the output to screen works as desired.

Comment: SET exclude="Folder A\Folder AB" isnt working for me. And as mentioned above, Folder AB is a Subfolder of Folder A in Folder Main. Or am I doing smth wrong?

Comment: It was an example, I amended it to a working example. See edit.